# How to calculate time difference in XQuery? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xquery

Example:

```
@x.modify('insert <age>【DATEDIFF(DAY,DateOfBirth,"2017-8-23")】</age>as last into /')
```

`DATEDIFF(DAY, DateOfBirth, "2017-8-23")` throws an error; how to code in this situation?

Comment: ***WHAT*** error do you get? Please post the exact and complete error so we know what we're facing.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put datediff or any t-sql function into xquery.  But you can put the results into xquery using an [sql variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable).  Consider this:

```
     DECLARE @x XML = ''
     DECLARE @dtDiff INT 

     SET @dtDiff = DATEDIFF(DAY,getDate(),'2017-8-23')

     SET @x.modify('insert <age>{sql:variable("@dtDiff")}</age>as last into /')
     SELECT @x as [xmlData]
```